# Unable to upload file in IE8 using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

Now, this code perfectly works fine in Firefox, but when I try to execute it on IE8 I'm getting the following error from the browser (**exactly after selecting the files**). I'm totally clueless about how to resolve it.

**IE8 Error:**

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) Timestamp: Thu, 2 Oct 2014 06:53:20 UTC


Message: 'length' is null or not an object Line: 2 Char: 2815 Code: 0 URI: http://localhost:8090/JQueryStrutsFileUploadTest/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js
```

**HTML Line:**

```
<form action="/fileUploadAction.do" id="uploadform" method="POST">
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" style="display: none;" multiple />
    <input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="document.getElementById('fileupload').click();" />
</form>
<h5 style="text-align:center"><i style="color:#ccc"><small>Max File Size: 2 Mb - Display last 20 files</small></i></h5>

<table id="uploaded-files" class="table" border="1" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
        <th>File Name</th>
        <th>File Size</th>
        <th>File Type</th>
        <th>Cancel Action</th>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Upload All" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JQuery Line:**

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var parent_files = []

$('#fileupload').change(function() {    
    var user_files = this.files;
    $.each(user_files, function( index, file ) {
        $("#uploaded-files").append(
            $('<tr/>')
            .append($('<td/>').text(file.name))
            .append($('<td/>').text(file.size))
            .append($('<td/>').text(file.type))
            .append($('<td/>').html("<a href='#' onclick='javascript:removeFiles(\""+ file.name +"\")'> Cancel </a>"))
        )//end $("#uploaded-files").append()

        parent_files.push(file);
        console.log(parent_files);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 doesn't support multiple files :(

Comment: Ya, think that is the root cause of the problem. Thanks alot :)

Comment: I wish I could say more, but, that's what it is.